# Open cv join nearest Rect contours

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My input image named "img" is as follows:

[image]

I have the following code to detect contours on this image:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


mask = np.zeros(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)


for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])

    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (255, 255, 255), 2)
    print(w,x,y)
```

I am getting the following output:

[image]

My question is how do I join the nearest contours on the last 3 lines on the image . In output I want 3 rectangle boxes covering the 3 lines of mrz. Ive referred https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/opencv-c-connect-nearby-contours-based-on-distance-between-them/2618#2618 but that method seems computationally expensive, I want something simple

Comment: If these rectangles are **always** at the same/similar position in your images, you can do as the link you posted but only on contours satisfying certain boundary conditions for x and y.

Comment: no they are not always at the same position they can occupy other positions as well, but their pattern remains constant

Comment: Can you categorize them into a finite number based on position?

Comment: No they are not represented by constant number (that is : everytime I cannot guarantee the boxes will be 16 as in above images) the number of boxes used to represent this MRZ pattern varies

Comment: I didn't mean the number of boxes but rather the number of possible positions they occupy in the image dataset that you have. Also, what is the purpose for doing this, OCR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below a relatively simple solution.  The comments explain the idea behind it.

```
import cv2, numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2:]

# y-coordinate of midline of rectangle
def ymid(y, h): return y+int(h/2)

# identify lines (l=0, 1, ...) based on ymid() and estimate line width
ym2l, l, l2w, rects = {}, 0, {}, []
for cont in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    rects.append([x, y, w, h])
    ym = ymid(y, h)
    if ym not in ym2l:
        for i in range(-2, 3):   # range of ymid() values allowed for same line 
            if ym+i not in ym2l:
                ym2l[ym+i] = l
        l2w[l] = w
        l += 1
    else:
        l2w[ym2l[ym]] += w

# combine rectangles for "good" lines (those close to maximum width)
maxw, l2r = max(l2w.values()), {}
for x, y, w, h in rects:
    l = ym2l[ymid(y, h)]
    if l2w[l] > .9*maxw:
        if l not in l2r:
            l2r[l] = [x, y, x+w, y+h]
        else:
            x1, y1, X1, Y1 = l2r[l]
            l2r[l] = [min(x, x1), min(y, y1), max(x+w, X1), max(y+h, Y1)]

for x, y, X, Y in l2r.values():
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (X-1, Y-1), (255, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here the result:
[image: rectangles]